# Issue with Sliding Drawer and Animations

Tags: android, animation, slidedown, slideup, slidingdrawer

I am working on a project where I should not use any XML file and sliding Drawer is must. But I found that Sliding Drawer is not possible through java coding, For this reason I started working on animations where a layout should move Up and Down same as sliding Drawer & ended with nothing.

Could someone help me with this issue

Comment: I didn't get by what you mean by 'ended with nothing'. Is it a problem with your code or you don't know how to use the `translate` animation?

Comment: TO be frank I dont know how to use tranlate animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't necessarily have to use the translate animation. You can use android's Sliding drawer. Also, there are many sliding drawer libraries on [Github](http://www.github.com).

But if you do want to use your own drawer you need the translate animation. So, get started with that. You can visit [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidAnimation/article.html) and [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/06/android-working-with-xml-animations/) to get started.

All the best!